# Show only a section of an image in WPF Datagrid rows?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, datagrid, bitmapimage

I have images (on local drive) that are of 200x275 in dimension and I'm filling one row in my data grid with them using the following code:

**XAML : DataGrid.Columns**

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="IMG" Width="SizeToCells">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Width="200" Height="275" Margin="0,0,0,-100" Source="{Binding Path=IMG}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

In my xaml.cs file I have `IMG` as a property of type `BitmapImage` (stores the uri as BitmapImage) and using a CollectionViewSource to update it with changes to the list of which includes a column for those images.

Displaying them is fine, but I only want to display a section of each image as a sort of preview (same width of 200px, 10px from the top, and only 50px in height - later I'll have the full image display when the small preview of it is clicked).

From the above bit of code you can see that I tried changing the Margin values (-100 to bottom) - which kinda works, but the last image in the list is displayed in full and extends past the bottom of the list.

Is there a better way of cropping 10px from the top, and then set the height to 50px without the image scaling down?

The only way I can think of doing it is creating a new bitmap from the bitmap image but I'm pretty sure that'd be really inefficient with hundreds of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try wrapping your Image control in a Grid with ClipToBounds=true. That should fix it. Just make sure the grid is sized to the *item* (50px high) and not auto-sized from the image or the clipping won't work as you expect.

Comment: Ah that works perfectly thanks, and I used Margin for the 10px on top. I did fiddle around with the ClipToBounds earlier but wasn't aware that I needed to contain the image in a grid, I assumed the bounds would be row container.